# React Redux JSON from Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-sheets, redux, react-redux

Creating a web page for our ski lodge, we are renting it out to people. I have a Google spreadsheet with pricing, dates and wether it is available for rent that specific date.

My previous page was written in AngularJS with TabletopJS fetching the data from the spreadsheet, but I thought it would be a good experience writing it in React and Redux without TabletopJS.

How would I go about fetching data from the JSON that the Google spreadsheet spits out? I have looked at the Redux tutorial of async actions, but I find it hard to implement with my own code.

Do you guys have any tips on how I should do this?

EDIT: Here is my angularjs code:
**tabletop-config.js**

```
'use strict';

angular
  .module('myApp')
  .config(tableTopConfig);

function tableTopConfig (TabletopProvider) {
  TabletopProvider.setTabletopOptions({
    key: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GJHfKQy24BFKNkYVjCfFtar1OCd4vJ8_TvFRheMKH90/pubhtml',
    simpleSheet: true
  });
}
```

**bookingController.js**

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('bookingController', bookingController);

  function bookingController($scope, Tabletop) {
    var vm = this;
    Tabletop.then(function(ttdata) {
      vm.data = ttdata[0];
    });
  }

})();
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need* `redux-thunk` or something similar to handle asynchronous actions. The `fetchTable` function below has to be updated with whatever your API is to get the spreadsheet data.

(*NOTE: Technically you can do without `redux-thunk`, but it will only be more complicated.)

```
// actions/spreadsheet.js
// --- Action-creators ---
function requestSpreadsheet() {
  return {
    type: 'SPREADSHEET_REQUEST'
  }
}


function receiveSpreadsheet(data) {
  return {
    type: 'SPREADSHEET_RECEIVED',
    payload: {
      data: data
    }
  }
}


function receiveSpreadsheetError(error) {
  return {
    type: 'SPREADSHEET_FAIL',
    payload: {
      error: error
    }
  }
}

// --- API ---
function fetchTable(tableInfo) {
  // Code related to API here. Should just return a promise.
  // Someting like...
  return fetch('spreadsheet url here')
}


// --- Thunks ---
function getSpreadsheetData(tableInfo) {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    // Tell reducers that you are about to make a request.
    dispatch(requestSpreadsheet())

    // Make the request, then tell reducers about
    // whether it succeeded or not.
    return fetchTable(tableInfo).then(
      data => dispatch(receiveSpreadsheet(data)),
      error => dispatch(receiveSpreadsheetError(error))
    )
  }
}
```

Then you'll need to have a reducer or reducers that listen for those actions and update the application state accordingly. You should think about how you want the application state to be shaped. I'm assuming nothing else about your application.

```
// reducers/spreadsheet.js
const initialState = {
  spreadsheetData: {}
  loading: false,
  errorMsg: ''
}

function spreadsheet(state = {}, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SPREADSHEET_REQUEST':
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      }

    case 'SPREADSHEET_RECEIVED':
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        spreadsheetData: action.payload.data,
        errorMsg: ''
      }

    case 'SPREADSHEET_FAIL':
      return {
        loading: false,
        errorMsg: action.payload.error 
      }
  }

}
```

Then you have your view logic in React that treats the entire view as a function taking in the app state and returning the HTML you would like to display. You need to `npm install --save react-redux` to allow your React components to "listen" for changes in your redux app state, so they will re-render accordingly.

```
// containers/Spreadsheet.js
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import SpreadsheetComponent from '../components/Spreadsheet'

// This function tells your SpreadsheetComponent about the
// parts of the app state that it should "listen" to. The 
// component will receive them as normal react props.
// These fields can be named whatever is most convenient.
function mapStateToProps(appState) {
  return {
    spreadsheetData: state.spreadsheetData,
    loading: state.loading,
    errorMsg: state.errorMsg
  }
}

// 
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SpreadsheetComponent)

// components/Spreadsheet.js
import React from 'react';

function Spreadsheet(props) {
  return (
    <h1>Here is the spreadsheet!</h1>
    <ul>
      {props.spreadsheetData.map(row => {
        return (
          <li>
            <RowStuff row={row} />
          </li>
        )
      })}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

And how do you wire all this stuff together?

```
// configureStore.js
import React from 'react'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import App from './components/App'

import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: It's actually possible to do without redux-thunk if the actual request is placed somewhere within component declaration, but yep, redux-thunk is pretty much more concise and definitely a good thing to know how to apply.

Comment: Good point, I think it's simpler for beginners to just stick with `thunk` to begin with, even though it can strictly speaking be done without. It allows for less mess in React's `componentWillMount` and other functions, which should just be extracted to Redux code anyway.